# Problema al umbralizar por bloques python opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Tengo una función que divide una imagen en bloques y umbraliza cada bloque por separado calculando un umbral para cada bloque, pero solo umbraliza la columna de la derecha y la pone a la izquierda.
Esta es la función:

```py
def umbralizarBloques(img, m, n, umbral):
    filas, columnas = img.shape
    x = int(filas/m)
    y = int(columnas/n)


    bloques = []
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            bloque=np.zeros((x,y), np.uint8)
            for k in range(x):
                for l in range(y):
                    bloque[k,l]=img[(i*x)+k,(j*y)+l]
        if umbral == "Otsu":
            bloque = umbralizar(bloque, calcularUmbralOtsu(bloque))
        if umbral == "General":
            bloque = umbralizar(bloque, calcularUmbralGeneral(bloque))

        bloques.append(bloque)

    ordenada = np.zeros((filas, columnas), np.uint8)
    l = 0
    o = 0
    for i in bloques:
        for j in range(x):
            for k in range(y):
                ordenada[(l*x)+j,(o*y)+k] = i[j,k]
        if l<n:
            l+=1
        if l==n:
            o+=1
            l=0
        cv2.imshow("Ventana",ordenada)
        cv2.waitKey (0)
    return ordenada
```

Los parámetros de la función son:
img: la imagen que se va a procesar
m: el número de divisiones en las filas
n: el número de divisiones en las columnas
umbral: el método de calculo del umbral a usar, otsu o general
esta es la imagen que uso y el resultado de la función:
[image: imagen original]

[image: resultado]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabula los if y el append de la primera parte. Cambialos indices l y o en la segunda parte.

```
    filas, columnas = img.shape
    x = int(filas/m)
    y = int(columnas/n)


    bloques = []
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            bloque=np.zeros((x,y), np.uint8)
            for k in range(x):
                for l in range(y):
                    bloque[k,l]=img[(i*x)+k,(j*y)+l]
            if umbral == "Otsu":
                bloque = umbralizar(bloque, calcularUmbralOtsu(bloque))
            if umbral == "General":
                bloque = umbralizar(bloque, calcularUmbralGeneral(bloque))

            bloques.append(bloque)

    ordenada = np.zeros((filas, columnas), np.uint8)
    l = 0
    o = 0
    for i in bloques:
        for j in range(x):
            for k in range(y):
                ordenada[(o*x)+j,(l*y)+k] = i[j,k]
        if l<n:
            l+=1
        if l==n:
            o+=1
            l=0
        cv2.imshow("Ventana",ordenada)
        cv2.waitKey (0)
    return ordenada
```